# calling javascript on document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery will not run my java script function on document ready.

```
cont += "<script>";
cont += "$(document).ready(function() {Puma.getReasonForBTI()});";
cont += "</script>";
```

JS function

```
Puma.getReasonForBTI = function() {
    var reason = document.getElementById("reasonId").value;
    var msql = "SELECT Pid FROM tPid WHERE Reason = 'reason'";
    sql = "action=getReasonForBTI&sql=" + encodeURIComponent(msql);
    objAjaxAd.main_flag = "getReasonForBTI";
    objAjaxAd.SendQuery(sql);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you doing with `cont`? So far I don't see any JavaScript which could possibly be executed when the page loads. The code you posted is not helpful without its context.

Comment: Where does `cont` come into play? Also, what's Puma? And are you actually sending SQL from JavaScript?

Comment: Are any errors being thrown?  More info, please.

Comment: This is so ripe for SQL Injection I don't even know what to do with myself.

Comment: cont is just a string var that is adding on html to the document.

Comment: Could you explain how someone could inject this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just add the DocReady to your JS?

```
Puma.getReasonForBTI = function() {
    var reason = document.getElementById("reasonId").value;
    var msql = "SELECT Pid FROM tPid WHERE Reason = 'reason'";
    sql = "action=getReasonForBTI&sql=" + encodeURIComponent(msql);
    objAjaxAd.main_flag = "getReasonForBTI";
    objAjaxAd.SendQuery(sql);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  Puma.getReasonForBTI()
});
```

**EDIT:**

Also, I would send `reason` by itself and Sanitize it server side, then put it into a query. Sending a SQL query over Javascript/AJAX is just asking for trouble.

Faux-Code:

```
sql("
    SELECT Pid
    FROM tPid 
    WHERE Reason = ?
", $ajax.reason)
```

**DOUBLE EDIT**

Also, putting `reason` in single quotes in a string does not evaluate the value of `reason`. Just figured I'd save you some future headache

```
var foo = "bar";
console.log("The value of foo is 'foo'");
=> "The value of foo is 'foo'"
console.log("The value of foo is " + foo);
=> "The value of foo is bar"
```

Comment: the JS located in a different file.

Comment: @MasterP, it shouldn't matter. DocReady can be called from any file as long as the file is loaded from within the code

Answer (score 1):

Try a chrome browser and the Development tools (F12).

1. Take a look at the errorconsole.
2. Fix the error
3. Change your Code, because **Someone can use YOUR code to delete any data from the underlying database**

**update**

```
var reason = document.getElementById("reasonId").value;
// reason is entered directly byy a user (or Mr. EvilHacker).
var msql = "SELECT Pid FROM tPid WHERE Reason = 'reason'";
// Here you create a SQL, which may sounds like this:

SELECT Pid FROM tPid WHERE Reason = ''; DROP table tPid;--'
```

if the evil hacker entered `';DROP table tPid;--` into the textbox. Look at [owasp.org](http://owasp.org) for further information

Comment: You can also use Dev Tools in IE (F12) or Firebug in Firefox

Comment: Yes, thats right. It just a quastion like "prefer vanilla or chocolate ice". (with one exception, I think)